# ASP.NET unit testing -- is there a shorthand way of specifying the needed attributes?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

My unit tests need the following attributes:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\projects\\dogs", "/dogs")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost/dogs")]
```

I'd hate to have to repeat these attributes for every test.  Is there a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to create a code snippet.

http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-3572/ms.help?method=page&id=85976AD9-4C9A-4E7B-896E-66EC6F955199&product=VS&productVersion=100&topicVersion=100&locale=EN-US&topicLocale=EN-US

If you use ReSharper it is really easy to add a "Live Template" that allows you to make the snippet more dynamic. I just created a video demo with your snippet [for you here](http://screenr.com/0wq).